# Can't seem to successfully use jQuery ajax .get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a server running locally (no authentication required) and when I do a GET / request to it using terminal I get some JSON. Now I want to do this on a website I made.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>HTTP Request to server</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="search-box"> URL: </label>
            <input id="search-box" type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary"> Go </button>
        <hr />
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search-button').click(function() {
                var url = $('#search-box').val();


                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $("#result").append(data);
                },"json");

                //$("#result").text(url);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get it to work, when I click the button nothing appears.

Comment: Your problem might be Same Origin Policy, check the console for errors.

Comment: Make sure the `url` is valid

Comment: im using nodes http-server and I get the message "GET /127.0.0.1:9080" Error (404): "Not found"", however at the same time, if I open another terminal and do "curl 127.0.0.1:9080" I get the JSON i want.

Comment: @memes I'm not sure if you can fetch json data from the server like this, could you try getJson instead and see if this returns anything? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson

Comment: didn't work but thanks for the suggestion, the fact im getting 404 not found on the node http-server output makes me think it has nothing to do with my js code but with the server configuration itself.

Comment: @memes Ahh sorry I didn't see your comment. Yes their is probably something wrong on the sever side. But once you solve that problem your probably going to need the getJson because the way you do it now it will return an object to you and it won't be displayed if you append it to a <p> element. Good luck on your server side quest, unfortunately I'm not much of a help there...

Comment: thank you friend :)

Comment: uhm... what are you putting in the search box?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:9080 which is the port my server is running on

Answer (score -1):

You can not directly send a request from Javascript to server asking for JSON if the server does not allow resource sharing with the client.

You will get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource.` error in the console panel of your browser.

Even if the server allows resource sharing then you can use [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) methods.

Comment: @downvoter. please also explain what you were expecting.